# How can I create a "setback" buffer for coastal lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I've been going a bit crazy in trying to create a "setback" buffer on QGIS for coastal lines in a map projecting this buffer outwards towards the sea. I've managed to create a normal Bidirectional buffer, but that's not the outcome that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no way to create a one-sided buffer for lines in QGIS.

You'll have an easier time converting your coast line to a land polygon an buffering that.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a regular 'two sided' buffer, then use the coastline to split it, and delete the half you do not want.

Answer (score 1):

"Setback" buffer is only meaningful for polygons data sets.  In QGIS you can obtain a "setback" buffer by providing a negative buffer distance in *Vector-> Geoprocessing Tools-> Buffer(s)...* or *Fixed distance buffer* in *Processing* (*QGIS geoalgorithms-> Vector geometry tools*).